# How to set rootURL in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-cli

I'm trying to change the roolURL in an Ember CLI app.  This is easy in a basic Ember app:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  rootURL: '/blog/'
});
```

Doing this in an Ember CLI app throws the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reopen' of undefined
```

The reason why I'd like to do this is that I'm going to have multiple Ember CLI apps inside of a rails app.  The URLs will look something like this:

```
/ --> rails
/foo --> rails
/api --> rails
/admin --> Ember CLI
/blog --> Ember CLI
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to update your config/environment.js as follows:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/blog/'
```

see http://www.ember-cli.com/#deployments for environment specific configurations.

Comment: Important! After making environment changes, you'll need to restart Ember CLI. That's what got me.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, which was about rootURL. You answered a question about baseURL, which was deprecated in Ember cli 2.7.